# Using awk to extract text from grep match and place side by side

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a bunch of `.jks` files in a directory. I would like to extract the alias name, valid from date and expiration date. Right now I have the following:

```
for f in *; do if [ -f $f ]; then echo "" |keytool -list -v -keystore $f | grep -e "Alias name:" -e "Valid from:"; fi done
```

which would output something like

```
Alias name: somehostname.com

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

.
.
.

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
```

With there being at least 1 cert for each alias name but at most `n` certs.

I would like the output format for the above to be as follows:

```
somehostname.com \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

{empty}          \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

.
.
.

{empty}          \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
```

`{empty}` means whitespaces for alignment. `\t` means `TAB` separator.

This would be the final output **for one** `.jks` file.
I'd like to do this for all the `.jks` files in the directory.

**How can I modify my existing command line script with awk to do this?**

Comment: I have formatted for clarity.

Comment: Remove all heading and trailing ` and unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: Why have the `sed` tag?

Comment: Do you actually want the string `{empty}` on the lines?

Comment: @Beta because I don't know if awk or sed is the better choice here. Wanted to include both options.

@tink No `{empty}` in this case is just meant to represent whitespace such that the bottom rows are aligned and shifted towards the right.

@Tiw keytool command just show a bunch of random garbled text and other information that I don't need. I do think grep is necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `GNU awk`, and use spaces to fill instead of `{empty}`,   can do it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="Alias name: *";FS="Valid from: *";}FNR>1{gsub(/until:/,"\t");gsub(/\n/,"");print $1 "\t" $2; i=3; while($i){for(j=0;j<length($1);j++)printf " "; print "\t" $i; i++;}}' file
```

With this `file`:

```
Alias name: somehostname.com

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
Valid from: Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Sat Jun 01 23:00:00 GMT 2062

Alias name: another.com

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Alias name: yetanother.com

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
```

Produces this output:

```
somehostname.com    Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019     Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
                    Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019     Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
                    Tue Feb 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019     Sat Jun 01 23:00:00 GMT 2062
another.com Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019     Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
yetanother.com  Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019     Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
                Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019     Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
```

Comment: How could I make it so that the columns are all fixed width so it looks neater?

Comment: @SamuelRodriguez Three ways: 1. Use an extra command to determine the longest domain first, then use it as fill length.  2. User multiple `TAB` as the *first* separator.  3. Use a relatively long fixed width  to place the first *column* (the domain plus the fill spaces).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty (or simple), but does what you're asking:

```
cat sam.awk
/Alias name:/ {
  count=0
  l=length($3);
  printf "%s ", $3
}
/Valid from:/ {
  count++;
  gsub(/Valid from:/, "\\t");
  gsub(/until:/, "\\t");
  space=0
  if(count!=1) {
    space=l-4
    printf "{empty}"
  };
  printf " %*s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",space,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15
}
```

As I don't have any jsk files to play w/ I took your actual output as input for my experiments (to emulate the output of several files I duplicated one entry and changed the hostname):

```
cat sam
Alias name: somehostname.com

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022 
Alias name: hostname.com

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022

Valid from: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 until: Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2022
```

Invoked like this `awk -f sam.awk sam` it gives the following:

```
awk -f sam.awk sam
somehostname.com  \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT
{empty}           \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT
{empty}           \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT
hostname.com  \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT
{empty}       \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT
{empty}       \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2019 \t Wed Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT
```